# How to make Excel support a custom file format?

Tags: excel, ms-office, add-in

Is there a way to make Microsoft Excel support a new file format for input and output - as a selectable file format in the "Open File" and "Save File" dialogs? Maybe by writing an addin or something like this?

My goal is to use Excel to read and write tabular data stored in a custom format - *let's say JSON but it's not decided yet*. I know that I could write an application that does the conversion from my custom format to the Excel format, but that's explicitly not I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean, support?  Do you mean, someone selects "open file", and then in the list of file types to open is '.JSON', and Excel knows how to open/parse it?

Comment: Exactly, I precised my question.